# Is there a way to save the georeferencing residuals table in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, georeferencing

I am conducting a georeferencing task for which I need to calculate statistics on the x and y residuals. I note that these are helpfully calculated in the control point table both before and after georeferencing Is there a way to copy or save these values from these tables? I note that it is possible to save the original control points, without residuals, but saving after the georeferencing does not seem to change the coordinates from the originals.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer appears to be No and this is for ArcGIS Pro 2.5. Suggest you head over to the [ESRI Ideas website](https://community.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas) and suggest it otherwise ESRI are unlikely to include this functionality in future versions.